# Error using struct.pack

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, struct

I am trying to create packed binary data, using struct.pack() in python3.x

It is giving me the below error, but I am unable to understand.

```
packed1 = struct.pack('>i4', 7, 8)

errorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-823-a27a6bc07ff4> in <module>()

----> 1 packed1 = struct.pack('>i4', 7, 8)

error: repeat count given without format specifier
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repeat count should be before the *i*

```
struct.pack('>4i', 7, 8, 3, 2)
```

Also you need 4 parameters not only 2

Comment: Thanks ! It worked.
Although I understand why it shud be 4 and not 2, why the repeat count shud be before i?

When I use packed = struct.pack('>i4sh', 7, b'spam', 8), it works perfectly well.

Comment: the 4s takes 4 chars *spam* try 2s and you'll get *sp*

Comment: I believe you are taking this example from the book Learning Python by O'Reilly. Essentially in chapter 4 he talks briefly about writing binary byte files. The first argument to struct.pack('>i4sh', 7, b'spam', 8) is a format string. > indicated big endian, i indicates 4 byte integer, 4s indicates 4 character string and h is 2 byte integer. Note the 4s requires a byte string.